# Checkbox only updates model after second click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Please look at the following Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/hwVL3xtnD9hGJLpULDjI?p=preview

When you click the checkbox the first time the model doesn't update.
Why does this happens?

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
      $scope.propdata = [];
      $scope.success ="loading..";
      var url = "api.json";
       $http({url:url,
         method:"GET"
       }).then(function (rs){
         $scope.propdata = rs.data[0];
         $scope.success ="done..";
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You json is returning has a `1` value, not a `true` or `false`. If you change your data to `true` or `false`, it will recognize the initial value. Another option is to cast the "1" to boolean, and then assign it.

Edit:

Another option is to set the `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` on your checkbox, so it recognizes the 0 and 1 values you are using. Notice the simple quotes after the double ones "'1'" to recognize the string. Example here:

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkbox {{font_size}}">
     <label for="garden_service">
          <input type="checkbox" id="garden_service"
                      ng-checked="propdata.garden_service==1" ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'"
                       ng-model="propdata.garden_service">Garden Service <br/>model value:{{propdata.garden_service}}
     </label>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/t280UjC3NYNtQt28W1wm?p=preview

Official docs link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: Great thanx! wasn't aware of the single quotes within the double quotes.